# getComputedStyle(elem,).getPropertyValue('font-size') is returning wrong value when element's fontSize is set in em

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to get font size of an element his way :
 `getComputedStyle(MyTargetElement , "").getPropertyValue('font-size')`

somehow this returns a wrong value it returns `16px` but expected is `14px` ,why?

```
<RootElement /> fontsze:14px 
  <GranParent /> fontsze:1rem 
    <Parent /> fontsze:1em
      <MyTargetElement /> fontsze:1em
```

what's  wrong here ?

Comment: `rems` take their sizing from the root element (`<html>`). In your case, `GrandParent` has font-size of 16px assuming `html` has 16px as font-size. And subsequent child element with `em` inherit font-size from `GrandParent`. In order to have `14px` as value, you need to assign `html` with 14px as font-size.

Comment: know that that's hy I provided the explanation , since rem take sizing from root element and my root element has font size of 14px I should be getting 14px as output not 16px

Comment: Root element for `rem` is `html` not your `RootElement `. You need to set font-size of html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RootElement of ReactJS application is **not** an actual root element of HTML (which is `<html>` element itself, and which is the basis of `rem` calculations): you have to mount your application somewhere, and (once again, almost always) it's not even a `<body>` element, rather one of its descendants.

If you didn't set up a font-size for `<html>` explicitly, the user-agent ends up using its own stylesheet, that's how you arrive to `16px` as a computed value for 1rem-1em-1em chain.